# mysql select max percent id and all row. or select latest insert

Tags: mysql

i have this table called "tblpercentage"

```
PercentID   Dividend    Rebates     Interest
    1           40          10          2   
    2           60          20          5
```

this is my query

```
SELECT MAX(PercentID)As PercentID,Interest FROM tblpercentage
```

but the problem is. it can only select PercentID = 2 and interest = 2 instead if 5. but i want is select all row with the max id. can anyone help me.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

for get the row related  to the max id you should use a subquery

```
  select PercentID,Interest from tblpercentage
  where PercentID = (SELECT MAX(PercentID) from tblpercentage)
```